# HTML5 game freezes in browser

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, game-physics

I'm trying to develop a game (Spaceship and Rocks) using only HTML5 and pure JavaScript.
But the game is freezing unexpectedly. Everything works fine before Spawning the rocks in CANVAS.
I'm not able to rectify the problem.
here's  my game in codepen:
http://cdpn.io/vJaoi

## update:

I've updated the code for the previous question

But the missile sprites when collide with the rocks, the rocks are popping out unevenly.

Any suggestions on colliding the roks and missiles.
Or better algorithms for collision detection in groups of sprites.

Comment: Just Feedback--not an answer: For better performance and less resource usage, you might (1) put the background image on a separate div that is placed directly behind the game canvas (2) check out requestAnimationFrame instead of using setInterval--RAF is well synchronized with display refreshes.  BTW, nice game imagery!  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This loop never ends :)

```
    while (distance < 100){
        rock_pos = [random(0, WIDTH), random(0, HEIGHT)];
    }
```

distance is never incremented

Comment: ooooppppssss!!!............. thank u @nils... i changed the loop to if condition.... u r a life saver.... :)

Comment: i was irritated by this loop...lol.. and i'm very happy now :D